# golang unmarshall unknown json data

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a use case where I need to unmarshal response from HTTP requests. I don't know the response format ahead of time but would just like to return the result upstream to web client (similar functionality to a proxy)
Normally I would just unmarshal like the following:

```
resp, _ = http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonPayload))
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
responseJson := make(map[string]interface{})
json.Unmarshal(body, &responseJson)
```

However, if the result is instead an array of JSON `[{},{}...]`
then I would need to do the following

```
var responseList []map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &responseList)
```

And if the result is a single string value like `"ok"` it would also require different unmarshaling methods

But If I don't know the response type ahead of time, how would I know how to unmarshal?

Comment: [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) represents arbitrary JSON documents, but if you just want to pass on the bytes, why unmarshal at all?

Comment: actually very good point, i should just return the []byte/string

Answer (score 3):

You can just unmarshall it as interface like :

```
var responseJson interface{}
json.Unmarshal(body, &responseJson)
```

To read the type of response:

```
switch resp := responseBody.(type) {
case string:
    fmt.Println(resp)
case float64:
    fmt.Println(int(resp))
default:
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that works fine for array and json types, but breaks when it's just a string like `ok`